# How to save vb.net combobox content into mysql table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, combobox

I have an issue here .. i cant save combobox content into my table ... all other data are successfully saved but the combo box is saved either 1 or zero .. what seems to be wrong?

My tables are designed through navicat .. does this have anything to do with my choice of data type? knowing that I chose the data type to be Text

This is my code and it shows no run errors

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim conStr As String = ("Data Source=localhost;user id=root;password=123456;database=sam;")
        Try
            Dim con As New MySqlConnection(conStr)
            Dim cmd As MySqlCommand

            For i = 0 To ComboBox4.Items.Count
                con.Open()

                Dim sqls As String = "INSERT INTO initial_nom(f_name,s_name,th_name,fo_name,app_no,adm_type) VALUES('" & TextBox1.Text & "', '" & TextBox2.Text & "', '" & TextBox3.Text & "', '" & TextBox4.Text & "'," & TextBox5.Text & ",'" & ComboBox4.SelectedIndex.ToString & "')"
                cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqls, con)
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Error in saving to Database. Error is :" & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

Comment: ComboBox4.SelectedIndex.ToString Have you debugged and seen what value is it having?

Comment: no, how do i do that??

Comment: done... nothing shows

Comment: Dim Teststr As String =ComboBox4.SelectedIndex.Value.ToString(), try this and see whats the value in Teststr

Comment: Use parameters, just a suggestion its a great practice to start now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SelectedIndex` is integer which point to index of the selected item. Assuming that combobox's data source contains collection of string, try to use `SelectedItem` instead, type-cast it to string :

```
DirectCast(ComboBox4.SelectedItem, String)
```

Comment: oh thank you it actually worked .. i just changed from selected index to selected item thanks alot everyone